# How can I get a pfm image?

Tags: darktable

I'm trying to analysis the darktable. So this is need pfm image file for noiseprofiling.
But I'm windows user so I can't get any some kind of pfm files.

Does anyone please give to me pfm image file? Or
If you can, would you please let me know any transformer tool to pfm?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by PFM file. For me this extension is related to Type1 postscript fonts

Comment: @Romeo Ninov darktable use .pfm extension image file. You can see the hash about darktable in my post.

Comment: Why do you want the PFM especially from darktable? It's just one program that can write PFM-files.

Comment: @sebix would you please let me know what does mean pfm's 1?

Comment: @gmotree Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @sebix If you use the darktable, So did you see that 3 parameters -c , a and b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org), there are also Windows releases available.

Use command line `convert yourImage.jpg convertedImage.pfm` to perform the conversion.

*Note*: You need to let the installer set environment variables (i.e. path) in order to access image magick `convert` tool from the command line.